# Calling an opened workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

this is what i currently have,

```
Dim mastertemp As Workbook
Dim testproject As Workbook

Set testproject = Workbooks("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\Test Project.xlsm")
Set mastertemp = Workbooks("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\MasterTemp.xlsx")

mastersheet.sheets("Sheet1").activate
```

the third line of code is giving me subscript out of range, any ideas?

I want to be able to jump between workbooks without the system giving me "workbook is already open, reopening would discard all changes etc"

Comment: Set it to a variable then refer to it.

Comment: If you are only doing this, you could try turning off events. At the top, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` then at the end, set that back to `True`.

Comment: Drop the parens when you make a procedure call without assigning a function's return value; they're superfluous... and they **will** eventually cause issues if they're a habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks("Test Project.xlsm")

do stuff
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\MasterTemp.xlsx")
do stuff

wbk.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the workbook is already open, then refer to it by name in the `Workbooks` collection:

```
Dim testProject as Workbook
Set testProject = Workbooks("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\Test Project.xlsm")
testProject.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
```

If you don't know whether the workbook is open, then you can use some error-handling logic, like:

```
Dim testProject as Workbook

On Error Resume Next
' Attempt to index this workbook from the open Workbooks collection:
Set testProject = Workbooks("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\Test Project.xlsm")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' If the above fails, then the workbook isn't open, so we need to open it:
    Set testProject = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\Test Project.xlsm")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: whenever i set the testproject to location, i keep getting an error "script out of range", any idea?

Comment: Set mastertemp = Workbooks("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\MasterTemp.xlsx")

Comment: @Qmnguy  Which of the two code snippets are you trying to run? Note that in the first snippet, the workbook must be open already (and the error is expected if it is not). I put this there to illustrate. The second snippet of code *should* handle the error, so unless you have configured your VBE to "Break on All Errors", the error shouldn't raise, and it should proceed to the `WOrkbooks.Open` statement.

Comment: The line you're trying to run actually doesn't exist in my code... so I'm not sure where that's coming from. Note that you'll need similar error-handling for each workbook you are attempting to access: If it's not open, you need to open it, and this can be handled using logic like in the above example.

Comment: i am working with the first one, both excel workbooks are open

Comment: You should revise your question to show the code *as you are currently attempting to implement it*. Also, ensure that both files are open in the *same* instance of Excel, otherwise you run in to other possible problems like opening a Read-Only version of the file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always know the name of your workbook you can do

```
workbooks("Test Project").sheets("Dashboard").Activate 'add the file extension to the name if you've turned on file extensions in windows explorer
```

If the workbook name might be changing (or evening if it isn't, and you'll be referring to the workbook multiple times) then findwindow's suggestion is the way to go.

```
dim TestWorkbook as workbook
set TestWorkbook=Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\zzz\Documents\Test Project.xlsm")
TestWorkbook.sheets("Dashboard").activate
```

I hope this helps.